# Javascript alert not working inside data toggle buttons

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, alert

```
<div class="xyz" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" onclick='alert("Hellooo");' name="test" value="Radio1" > Radio
  </label>
</div>
```

Javascript alert box is not working with data toggles(Bootstrap is loaded).
Can someone help?
The code snippet is pasted above.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I copied it to plunkr and it is working?

Comment: It works for me too [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hftv9zd1/)

Comment: some navigators dont support onclick in radio button, replace onclick with onchange and it should be working fine

Comment: With bootstrap http://plnkr.co/edit/fy8xvQFQMqb0Kpa7fYrN?p=preview

Comment: @BünyaminSarıgül 
Thnx for the response mate, but sorry that I modified my code before posting my original problem.
I had loaded jquery followed by Bootstrap script;
I had bootstrap modal running;
Now, when I try to run modal with jquery enabled I am not getting js alert..
When I override BS script with jquery js alert works but BS modal doesn't open..
Please see fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kashyap_coding/gy2sL731/